Excell Cell Notes & Comments preventing shapes applied to cell from fitting correctly
I have an Excel worksheet that lists a variety of equipment, and uses a legend to associate different statuses with each piece of equipment using interior fill. This worked great until I realized some equipment could have more than one status. I tried to use a gradient, but it wasn’t effective. Then, I tried adding extra colored characters to the cell, but it became overcrowded. Eventually, I settled on applying colored shapes to cells with up to four quadrants, and placing the cell content in a text box above the shapes. This works perfectly with one exception. The shapes and text fit perfectly in each cell, unless the cell has a note or a comment. The note/comment indicator causes the shapes to shift to the left, bleeding over the left border and appearing to leave empty space under the cell comment. I’ve tried changing the offset and other settings, but I simply cannot get the shapes to cover the comment indicator. I can’t remove the comments as they are needed, but the indicator doesn’t need to be visible as long as hovering over the cell still brings up the comment. Any advice on how to get shapes to fit within the confines of a cell without the comment indicator misaligning them would be appreciated.

In response to FunThomas, below is the VBA I'm using to do this.
With ws.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, left, top, width, height)
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(colorIndex) 
        .line.Visible = msoFalse
    End With

With ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, cell.left + commentOffset, top, cell.width - commentOffset, cell.height)
       .TextFrame.Characters.Text = cell.Value
       .TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Fill.Transparency = 0
       .Fill.Transparency = 1
       .TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
       .TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
   End With   


